Как объявить переменную  в Javascript?
Здравсвуйте. Возник такой вопрос, как объявить переменную . У меня это не получается, выдает Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token. Причем такое происходит только с эмодзи, буквенные переменные успешно создаются.

Имена переменных в JavaScript представляют собой произвольный набор алфавитно-цифровых символов, знака подчёркивания _ или знака доллара $. При этом названия не должны начинаться с цифровых символов.

Ну вы бы код то добавили, на котором проблема возникает. Иначе это ни о чём вопрос.

@CrazyElf, а много вариантов? var 

@Qwertiy var, const, let, но хотелось бы видеть таки код )

Нашел ответ. Нужно сделать так:
this[''] = true;
console.log(this['']);


this не всегда и не везде доступно

К тому же, это не переменная.
